# Does Tensorflow or Pytorch work on RTX 20xx super series

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, cuda, pytorch

I'm going to buy a new gpu to learn deep learning. The new Nvidia RTX 2060 Super seems to best fit my needs. But I wonder that is it compatible with CUDA and tensorflow or pytorch now?

Comment: Nvidia GPUs do provide CUDA extension which is able to run Tensorflow-gpu and Pytorch. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/rtx-2060-vs-gtx-1080ti-in-deep-learning-gpu-benchmarks-cheapest-rtx-vs-most-expensive-gtx-card-cd47cd9931d2) post compares performance of RTX2060 with that of GTX 1080Ti on deep learning benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

I have bought same VGA a few days ago and using it.
tested it, it works fine in Python (I used numby library) and used CUDA 10.1

Answer (score 0):

It [seems like](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042920/cuda-setup-and-installation/which-version-of-cuda-can-work-with-rtx-2080/) that RTX series support compute capability 7.5 which is compatible with cuda 10. You should be fine running deep learning with this card.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a RTX2070 super but had some trouble setting up tensorflow. I followed the guide below:

https://medium.com/@cjanze/how-to-install-tensorflow-with-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-with-cuda-10-nvidia-gpu-312a693744b5

*Make sure you install the latest driver (mine is 430.40; 430.26 didn't correctly show my GPU name) and CUDA 10.0 and NOT 10.1...

**I had an error when verifying that cuDNN was working... follow the steps below copied from (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025801/cudnn/cudnn-test-did-not-pass/):

Open

/usr/include/cudnn.h

And change the line:

```
#include "driver_types.h"
```

to:

```
#include <driver_types.h>
```

***edit: Just installed pytorch and it seems to be working as well